# Logistic regression vs. linear regression on class probabilities

Tags: regression, logistic, modeling, linear-model

I have a bunch of data points, each of which represent a success or failure. Each data point is from one of ~40 conditions, each of which contains approximately 40 data points. All of my predictor variables vary by condition rather than by individual point. Ultimately, I want to understand how each predictor variable influences the probability of success.

Would it be more appropriate for me to calculate percentage successes for each class and do a linear regression to predict these values, or for me to do a logistic regression on the individual points?

Example data:

```
Condition Var1 Var2 Var3 Succes 
 A         1.5  20   .4   yes
 A         1.5  20   .4   yes
 A         1.5  20   .4   no
 A         1.5  20   .4   no
 B         2.0  10   .6   no
 B         2.0  10   .6   no
 B         2.0  10   .6   yes
 B         2.0  10   .6   no
 C         1.7  15   .2   no
 C         1.7  15   .2   yes
 C         1.7  15   .2   yes
 C         1.7  15   .2   yes
```

Comment: That's far from the only choice you have. Percent and proportion data can be also be handled with logit models; your statistical software is very limited if it doesn't allow that. Linear regression with proportions (sometimes called the linear probability model) has its defenders, but it's certainly not the only choice.

Comment: I'm using R, so I'm totally open to other options. Those were just the two that immediately came to mind.

Comment: I am not in any sense an R expert, as I am only a very occasional user, but as you might expect it's totally up to the task here. I can't advise on which package to use.

Comment: It sounds like your predictors are confounded with the conditions. Do they vary between conditions? What are the conditions & the predictors? Can you paste in a small example dataset?

Comment: I guess you could say that the predictors are confounded with the conditions in that the predictors describe the way the conditions are different from each other. I don't actually care about the conditions, themselves, though, just the predictors. Does the example dataset I just added in clarify it at all?

Comment: So, aside from the class variable, you have 3 continuous variables & N=1600? Are there at least 1 success & 1 failure in every class?

Comment: i think you're confusing yourself by thinking of a condition variable existing. logistic regression will be easier to understand -- for each 1 unit increase in variable A, the chances of success will increase x%